# Can I add a class to an HTML.ActionLink in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have this code and would like to add a class to the link. Is it possible to do this in MVC3?

```
Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
```

Comment: class as in "public class MyClass {...}" or class as in "<a class='form-control' href='/MyController/MyAction'>Create New</a>" ?

Answer (score 158, accepted):

Yes, you can just add another parameter with object representing css class:

```
Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create", CONTROLLERNAME, null, new { @class= "yourCSSclass"} )
```

It can be translated to:

```
Html.ActionLink(link text, action name, controller name, route values object, html attributes object)
```

Edit:

**To add custom styles, use this:**

```
Html.ActionLink(
"Create New",
"Create",
CONTROLLERNAME,
null,
new { @class= "yourCSSclass", @style= "width:100px; color: red;" }
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answers. But now I am confused because I see three different ways of doing this that all have different parameters. Can someone give me some idea which might be best. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Sango: First parameter is actual link text that will be shown. Second paramter is name of action. Third is name of a controller. Fourth is object containing route values (ie. object that you need to pass to the route/action) - you don't need this one in this case, so just make it 'null'. And the last one is htmlAttributes object that got properties like 'class' which adds provided string/s as a css class to your link. You can see more at already mentioned [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492124.aspx). Just note, that the answer from Rhapsody doesnt work because of..

Comment: There is no "best". They are all overloads which point to the same underlying code for rendering an achor tag. Which overload to choose depends on what you need in the URL.

Comment: Thanks very much to everyone. I now have the code working and it looks great.

Answer (score 18):

```
@Html.ActionLink("ClickMe",  // link text
                 "Index", // action name
                 "Home",  // controller 
                 new { id = 2131 }, // (optional) route values
                 new { @class = "someClass" }) // html attributes
```

Comment: @RPM - quick question. Can I specify something like width to be different for this link? My button text is wider than normal and I would like to be able to modify the width.

Comment: @Sango: Check my answer to see how to add custom styles to your link.

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't work. It just specifies a parameter called width with a value of 100px in the address route :-(

Comment: @Sango: Seems like my answer is inivisble to you. Nevermind then. So much for trying to help with working answer since beginning :)

Comment: btw using `@style` is bad practice. IMO it's just as bad as using `<div style="color:red;">`. Use a CSS class.

Answer (score 8):

```
Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "className" })
```

Answer (score 5):

According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492124.aspx), this should do the trick:

```
Html.ActionLink("LinkText", "Action", "Controller", new { }, new {@class="css class"})
```

**Edit:** Thanks for noticing Dampe, I updated the code sample.

Comment: -1, **this doesn't work**. You got switched order of controller name parameter and action name parameter. You can see correct order in my answer.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the ActionLink overload which takes an htmlAttributes parameter to add a class to the generated element:

```
Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create", new {}, new { @class = cssClass });
```