# Access Html.ActionLink property in Controller file

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, sitecore

I need to access practiceid property in my controller file please help how I can access this

```
<a href="" practiceid="df3d4335671b4fa880aebc2a6fc56869">Corporate</a>
<a href="" practiceid="26f4c9f5444b485c9d974f75361fa8ca">Tax &amp; Employee Comp/Exec Benefits</a>
<a href="" practiceid="40b0a3a0b2744fafae0475756693c37f">Business Finance &amp; Restructuring</a>
```

Regulatory

My csHtml code is as follows:

```
@foreach (var facetData in Model.SearchResultItems.Facets.Select((x) => new { Item = x.Key, Index = x.Value }))    
{
    <tr>
        <td>
           @Html.ActionLink(@facetData.Index, "Search","Search", new { practiceid = @facetData.Item })
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

and controller code is as follows:

```
public ActionResult Search(string practiceid)
{

}
```

But I'm not getting anything in my practiceid parameter.

Answer (score 1):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5907530/can-i-add-a-class-to-an-html-actionlink-in-mvc3).

What you want to do is to add parameters to the tag, not to the link. Which means you should leave fourth argument null and use fifth instead. ie.

```
@Html.ActionLink(@facetData.Index, "Search","Search", null, new { practiceid = facetData.Item })
```

And [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504988%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) for this helper method with focus on fifth parameter.

Comment: No success. After applying the same as mentioned above still getting the null value as Parameter specified in action as well as in Request it gives me the null

Comment: Ok, can you check if Model.SearchResultItems.Facets contains the data you would expect? Ie. connect the with the debugger to the action which returns the problematic view and see what is in the Facets object.

Answer (score 0):

Add the extra null

```
@foreach (var facetData in Model.SearchResultItems.Facets.Select((x) => new { Item = x.Key, Index = x.Value }))    
{
    <tr>
        <td>
           @Html.ActionLink(@facetData.Index, "Search","Search", new { practiceid = facetData.Item }, null)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: No success after adding this null value as parameter