# parameters and class name in @Html.ActionLink

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html.actionlink

How can I include parameters and class name in @Html.ActionLink

```
@Html.ActionLink(item.Name, item.ActionName, item.ControllerName, new  
RouteValueDictionary(item.Parameters), new Dictionary<string, object>{{"class",item.ClassName}}))
```

Error I get is: Ambiguous invocation: void Write(object)(in class _

The above doesn't work. Thanks.

Comment: Please provide your non working code.  :)

Comment: This is my nonworking code: @Html.ActionLink(item.Name, item.ActionName, item.ControllerName, new RouteValueDictionary(item.Parameters), new Dictionary<string,object>{{"class",item.ClassName}}))

Comment: I think this is what you are after. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5907530/can-i-add-a-class-to-an-html-actionlink-in-mvc3