# How can i add additional html child elements in an MVC ActionLink?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I would like to have the below html markup in MVC

```
<a href="/Home/ShoppingCart" class="view-cart">
<span data-hover="View Cart"><span>Cart</span></span></a>
```

but when i use this one

```
@Html.ActionLink("Cart", "ShoppingCart")
```

the result is

```
<a href="/Home/ShoppingCart">Cart</a>
```

So, how can i add that attributes and extra markups?

The problem is basically with the `<spans>` involved, which i do not know how to render them within the hyperlink.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5907530/can-i-add-a-class-to-an-html-actionlink-in-mvc3 shows how to add class attribute to ActionLink

Comment: [This overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.LinkExtensions.ActionLink%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,System.String,System.String,System.Object,System.Object%29) - `@Html.ActionLink("Cart", "ShoppingCart", null, new { @class = "xxxx" })`

Comment: @StephenMuecke This overload, adds the class but within the hyperlink there are extra markups which i do not have a clue on how to add them. For example the result is <a class="view-cart" href="/Home/Create">Cart</a> which has nothing to do with the desired output.

Comment: You cant do that using `@Html.ActionLink()` - you will need to use `<a href="@Url.Action("ShoppingCart")" class=".."><span>...</span></a>` (or create you own `HtmlHelper` extension method is if something you regularly do)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot add additional html elements inside the `<a>` element generated by `@Html.ActionLink()`. You will need to use

```
<a href="@Url.Action("ShoppingCart")" class="view-cart">
  <span data-hover="View Cart">
    <span>Cart</span>
  </span>
</a>
```

If its something you do regularly, you could consider creating you own `HtmlHelper` extension method which generates the markup for you