# How to add a class in Html.ActionLink

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to pass an int value from a View to a class, which later calls another function based on the int value.
The class I'm calling is called `DataFetch.cs` which has a function named `GetLogs(int x);`

What I have in the View is;

```
@Html.ActionLink("Connect",
            "GetLogs()", "DataFetch", new {id = item.MacNum}, new { @class = "DataFetch" })
```

^This gives me the url:

```
http://localhost:xxx/DataFetch/GetLogs()/1
```

Which obviously isn't what I want.

UPDATE:

```
function GetCloud()
    {
        console.log("insidefunc");
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/DataFetch/GetLogs?id=' + 1,

            data: 1,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                alert("done")
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                alert("Failed: " + response.responseText);
            },
            error: function (response) {
                alert("Error: " + response.responseText);
            }
        });
    }
```

This did not work either.

Comment: The question in its current state is unclear as it is incomplete and would require too many questions to clarify what is being asked. Read [ask] and then provide a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce your problem, allowing us to better understand what is being asked.

Comment: @Nkosi an HtmlActionLink that calls a class which has a function in it with an int parameter, how is this not clear?

Comment: You have not provided the desired url. You basically showed. This is what I have, this is what is gave me but I do not want that.

Comment: @Nkosi something like this? `http://localhost:xxx/DataFetch/GetLogs(1)`

Comment: That is not valid. Based on the code snippet provided, the resulting url is correct for what was given. Hence the confusion when you say it is not what you wanted

Comment: That fact that people are answering your question incorrectly represents how unclear the question is. Refer to my original comment. Not much help can be provided till the question has been clarified and proper information provided.

Comment: He wishes to call a class and a method which are not controller and action through ActionLink. this is not possible as it is not the intend of Razor ActionLink. He will have to you an ajax call to the class.

Comment: again this: http://localhost:xxx/DataFetch/GetLogs(1) is not valid!!! you cannot do this through action link or ajax! you need to learn more about mvc routing and webapi as well.

Comment: @BarrJ that is exactly what I want.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML.ActionLink method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200476/html-actionlink-method)

Answer (score 1):

Yes:

```
 @Html.ActionLink("ClickMe",  // link text
                     "Index", // action name
                     "Home",  // controller 
                     new { id = 2131 }, // (optional) route values
                     new { @class = "someClass" }) // html attributes
```

In order to learn more about ajax routing and calls use this:

[Jquery ajax tutorial](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

[Call a method with jquery ajax](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/8911c4/how-to-call-C-Sharp-methodfunction-using-jquery-ajax/)

This will give you enough info to begin with.

Comment: This isn't what I asked. I saw this here already: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5907530/can-i-add-a-class-to-an-html-actionlink-in-mvc3

Comment: It is exactly what you asked: "the int value. The class I'm calling is called DataFetch.cs which has a function named GetLogs" the class, is the controller. The method is the  Action. You cannot call a class which is not a controller and a method which is not an action in @Html.ActionLink. you will have to use ajax. Look at the method definition.

Comment: this is the syntax to pass values from view - to model - to cotroller or view - to action method. You do not specify it in the method but in the url - you issue a get request. please read more about routing before asking questions like this.

Comment: This will give me this: http://localhost:2078/Home/Index/1 but I do not intend to goto Home controller or its Index method. I want it to goto a class name DataFetch and then its method called GetLogs and pass the value `1` to that method.

Comment: excellent, then you will have to use jquery.Ajax. you cannot navigate to a non controller class and non action method thourgh razor.

Comment: any example or link to learn from?

Comment: I will edit my answer for you :)

Comment: can you write that function? I tried it but it throws the same controller error.

Comment: you will need to add the class an method code to your question

Answer (score 1):

You Can Directly Go to that Function By This ! this will also provide the parameter value which is required by that function

```
" @Url.Action("GetLogs","DataFetch",new { id = item.MacNum} ) "
```

for using this you have to create an anchor tag

```
<a href="@Url.Action("GetLogs","DataFetch",new { id = item.MacNum} )"> Connect</a>
```

if you want any thing else don't Vote down my answer ! just let me know in comments  i will do that

Comment: @Html.ActionLink is an anchor tag! This is the difference between url.action and html.ActionLink! the behavior is the same!

Comment: But it will call your function GetLogs in the class DataFetch and it will provide a int value !   what exactly you want

Comment: Just as Html.ActionLink! but you will not have to create an anchor tag because ActionLink will do it, it is meant for it! his code is good, he does not understand how routing works. meaning, this is not a code issue at all!

Comment: could u please write a url where u wanna go ?  either what i understand is that ! you are just using "()"  in your action link  in place of  action value which is not correct !

Comment: @SyedMunisAli  I want it to goto a class name DataFetch and then its method called GetLogs and pass the value 1 to that method

Comment: just  remove these "()" from GetLogs()  it will do that !

Answer (score 0):

```
@Html.ActionLink("Click Here",  // link text
                     "GetMyLogs", // you action name
                     "Home",  // you controller name
                     new { id = 1 }, // (optional) route values
                     new { @class = "someClass" })
```

well, what i suggest you to do is, on the click of the above ActionLink you should goto some action(your action) in a contoller(your controller) and in that action, you should create object of class(which you want to access) like this

```
public ActionResult GetMyLogs(int id){
    DataFetch Object_DataFetch  = new DataFetch();
    ObjectMyClass.GetLogs(1);
....
....
return "";
}
```

Hope this will help